# How to scrape HTML with VBA

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to make macros by scraping category names and  numbers for results from eBay. Here is the URL:
https://www.ebay.com/b/Interior-Design-Services/50342/bn_2311378

I want to add the text "1-48 of 52 Results" in a sheet I can't get any results if I use div or h2 tags.
Here is the HTML page code

```
<div class="srp-controls__row-cells">
    <div class="srp-controls__control srp-controls__count">
        <h2 class="srp-controls__count-heading">1-48 of 52 Results</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my VBA script:

```
Sub get_title_header()
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
sURL = Cells(i, 1)

wb.navigate sURL
'wb.Visible = True

While wb.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

'HTML document
Set doc = wb.document

Cells(i, 2) = doc.GetElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText

On Error GoTo err_clear
Cells(i, 3) = doc.GetElementsByTagName("div")(10).innerText
err_clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
wb.Quit
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Columns.AutoFit
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Excel VBA to scrape HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098948/using-excel-vba-to-scrape-html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `GetElementsByClassName` instead of `GetElementsByTagName`

for example

```
On Error GoTo err_clear
Cells(i, 3) = doc.GetElementsByClassName("srp-controls__count-heading")(0).innerText
```

Comment: Thx you now it work  but maybe know why other result not scarping , i mean some times got empty cell, maybe  you know how to fix it  for take all result all time